# MySQL - sort comma separated string in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | title      | numbers      |
| 2   | Title 1    | 2,8,5        |
| 3   | Title 2    | 50,7,9,4     |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

Is it possible to sort within the column? In this case in column numbers.

I need to output ordered numbers column as follows:

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | title      | numbers      |
| 2   | Title 1    | 2,5,8        |
| 3   | Title 2    | 4,7,9,50     |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

Something like:

```
SELECT id, title, SORT_FUNC(numbers) from table
```

I was looking for some function in MySQL documentation, but I found nothing.

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad db design. You should read about normalization.

Comment: Smells like bad database design. If you will transform this `numbers` column to the separate table having only one number in a column but multiple rows for the same id - it will significantly simplify the things.

Comment: I know, but it can be done?

Comment: There is no builtin string splitting function in MySQL. You can try to implement it by yourself using bunch of `instr` and `substring`.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev There are a few [mentioned here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) but nothing that will do what is required

Comment: Bad database design will almost always get you in this sort of pickle. Can we ask why you want this done

Comment: Consider rethinking why you need to store these numbers like this. If indeed you have no choice in the matter, then I would advise using a language like PHP to do it in code.

Comment: I agree with the above comments as well. Isn't a good idea to store this way. In any case, if you need to store them as comma separated, then you might as well want to store them sorted in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll remake

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not really a good idea.

As an example, you can split a comma separated list up by generating a range of numbers and using that with SUBSTRING_INDEX to get each element. However the range of numbers needs to be as big as the max number of delimited values.

You could then use GROUP_CONCAT to join the list back together in the right order. Note that the order will be different depending on whether you have cast the split up values as numbers / integers or left them as strings.

```
SELECT id, title, GROUP_CONCAT(aNumber ORDER BY aNumber)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, title, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers, ',', tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt + 1), ',', -1) AS UNSIGNED) AS aNumber
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 AS acnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 AS acnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    WHERE LENGTH(numbers) - LENGTH(REPLACE(numbers, ',', '')) >= tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt
) sub0
GROUP BY id, title;
```

Demonstrated here on SQL fiddle (if SQL fiddle decides to work):-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9703ee/4

First select is casting the values as integers to sort them numerically, 2nd one isn't casting them but just leaving them as strings, hence the sort order is different.